# what is good way to store player level unlock in a tower defence game using cocos2D ?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, store

All i want is just to store the level advancement like angrybirds.
What is the best way ?

The game is for iOS devices.

Is the best way a Core Data storage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rarely there is a 'best' way to do something. If you're already using Core Data in your app, then it would be easy to save the state there. Other solutions are to use the NSUserDefaults or even writing to a file in the Documents folder.

Comment: no core data is not implemented in the app, so that is the reason that i've asked. all i want is just a simple way, because all i am saving is the user advancements ( unlocking levels )...